# Increasing the JVM heap memory using Xmx doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, memory, java-8, heap-memory

I'm developping a javafx application which has much ui interfaces, and while opening many windows, the **jvm** start consumming much memory (**going up tp 350mb**).

When it arrives to **360mb**, the programs starts **lagging** and end up by being **crashed** (nothing works, screen blocks ...) and the console show a `OutOfMemoryException` with `Java Heap Space error`

I've **6gb** of memory in my computer, and tried to start the `.jar` file using `-Xmx` param, but still the operating system doesn't allow the **jvm** to consume more memory.

Is there anything else i should specify so that the jvm may be able to get as much memory as it needs ?

Comment: Show the arguments you're using to incrwsde the size.

Comment: Let me summarize the problem with my own words: the question is how to use machine learning for garbage collection improvement under the special requirement of efficient memory usage. A concrete algorithm wasn't given, so it's perhaps a simple reinforcement learning issue.

Comment: You could look at https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html as it may not be heap. You could also use a memory visualization to see what is the actual cause. https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/using-visualvm-to-visualize-gc-and-memory-utilization-of-your-java-app-e3f0b6dec4a6

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys i was giving the 1024 as a param to the application instead of the jvm ... sorry for late answer... now the app reaches 650mb and doesn't crash at all, it's fine but isn't 650mb a little bit tooo much ? (i've got a rich user interface) .. by the way i'll try those memory visualization tools to find out a clue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to ensure that you're using:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar YourApplication.jar
```

and not:

```
java -jar YourApplication.jar -Xmx1024m
```

Anything after the .jar is considered as argument passed to your executable Jar.

Comment: Thanks ! Amazing ! , now my application can reach 650mb and doesn't crash anymore ! i was writing the command wrongly :/ ... but 650mb isn't too much ? (got a rich user interface) .. sorry for late answer